# Generalized Directional Derivative of $-|x| $ (minus absolute $x$) (Clarke Derivative)

Tags: analysis, derivatives, set-valued-analysis

I am having hard time calculating the Generalized Directional Derivative (Clarke Derivative) of $f(x)=-|x|$ at $x=0$.
The answer is $f^{\circ}(0;v)=|v|$.

The Generalized Directional Derivative is defined as

$f^{\circ}(x;v)=\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}} \displaystyle{\sup_{x \downarrow  0}} \frac{f(y+tv)-f(y)}{t}$

On this website,
https://mathematix.wordpress.com/2021/10/13/generalized-directional-derivatives-some-examples/, the calculation of $f^{\circ}(0;v)$ when $f(x)=|x|$ and $f(x)=-|x|$ are shown and they have the same answer which is $|v|$.

I got stuck with the calculation of $f^{\circ}(0;v)=|v|$ when $f(x)=-|x|$. How come $f^{\circ}(0;v)=|v|$ for $f(x)=-|x|$ and $f(x)=|x|$ are the same? Can someone show me how to calculate $f^{\circ}(0;v)$ for $f(x)=-|x|$ in detail?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your definition. Did you mean $y\to x$ and $t\downarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1):

You always have $h \mapsto f^{\circ}(x; h)$ is positive homogenous you only need to compute for $h=\pm 1$. Since $| \cdot|$ is Lipschitz with rank one you always have $|f^{\circ}(x;\pm 1)| \le 1$.

$f^{\circ}(0; +1) = \limsup_{t \downarrow 0, y \to 0} {-|y+t| +|y| \over t} \ge \limsup_{t \downarrow 0, y<-t} {t \over t} = 1$ and similarly
$f^{\circ}(0; -1) = \limsup_{t \downarrow 0, y \to 0} {-|y-t| +|y| \over t} \ge \limsup_{t \downarrow 0, y>t} {t \over t} = 1$.

Hence $f^{\circ}(x; h) = |h|$.

A similar argument shows that for the Euclidean norm we have $(-\|\cdot\|)^{\circ}(0; h) = \|h\|$.

Comment: I missed the minus initially.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the post you referenced. Have a look at Proposition 3, which states that
$$
(-f)^{\circ}(x; h) = f^\circ(x; -h).
$$
If we apply this to $f(x) = -|x|$ at $x=0$ we have
$$
(-|{}\cdot{}|)^{\circ}(0; h) = |{}\cdot{}|^{\circ}(0; -h) = |-h| = |h|.
$$

Comment: In your proof, why $y = z +th$??. Shouldn't it be $y = z-th$??

Comment: @RudGud where exactly?

Comment: At <https://mathematix.wordpress.com/2021/10/13/generalized-directional-derivatives-some-examples/>, in the proof of Proposition 3, you wrote 'Define $z = y + th$' and then you wrote 'Additionally, $y = z + th$'. How did you do it?